# Cannot Get ReadFile to work with a Physical Drive

Tags: c#, readfile, hard-drive, drive, createfile

I can get ReadFile to read a simple text file, but cannot get it to work correctly with a physical drive.  I get the error "The parameter is incorrect" from GetLastError.  My code is as follows and provides more information:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ReadFileTest
{
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern unsafe uint GetLastError();

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern unsafe System.IntPtr CreateFile
    (
        string FileName,          // file name
        uint DesiredAccess,       // access mode
        uint ShareMode,           // share mode
        uint SecurityAttributes,  // Security Attributes
        uint CreationDisposition, // how to create
        uint FlagsAndAttributes,  // file attributes
        int hTemplateFile         // handle to template file
    );

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern unsafe bool ReadFile
    (
        IntPtr hFile, 
        [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, 
        out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, 
        IntPtr lpOverlapped
    );

    const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x050000000;
    const uint GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000;
    const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 1;
    const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;

    const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
    const int INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        unsafe 
        {
            // Reading a simple text file works perfectly:
            //IntPtr handle = CreateFile("D:\\Test.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

            // CreateFile of a physical drive gives me a valid handle.
            // But when attempting to read the drive, (all of my drives give the same result), I get the error "The parameter is incorrect."
            IntPtr handle = CreateFile(@"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

            // GetLastError returns this:
            // ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER87 (0x57)
            // The parameter is incorrect.

            byte[] b = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            uint n = 1;

            while (n != 0)
            {
                bool ret = ReadFile(handle, b, (uint)5, out n, (IntPtr)0);
                uint e = GetLastError();
            }

        }
    }
}
}

// I have unmounted the physical drive and run the test with the same results.
// I tried using pointers for the parameters, same result.
// I tried different variations of options for CreateFile.
// Don't know which parameter is giving the error.
```

Comment: Are you running elevated? (ISTR normal users cannot read the device directly.)

Comment: Side note: you do know that you should be using [GetLastWin32Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx) instead of PInvoke `GetLastError` directly? (not sure why you showing GetLastError call as it makes sample longer).

Comment: Also, you're not checking the result of the `ReadFile`: successful API calls do not always clear the error value.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `5` is invalid size to read when reading from raw devices - should be aligned to some block size. Something like `0x1000` has better chance to succeed.

Make sure to carefully read [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation. Consider reading one of editions of "Windows Internals" book if you really going to explore low level APIs.